# How to create Affix(Prefix + Suffix) embeddings in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am working on a named entity recognition task. Traditional method is to concatenate word embeddings and character level embeddings for creating a word representation first. I want to also use affix embeddings to better understand the relation between the tags and the words.

For example the words "Afghanistan" and "Kajikistan" are clear examples of Location. Here the suffix "istan" or "tan" will be useful to identify future "location" tags. So I want to extract the suffixes and prefixes of all the words and create embeddings for them, and then concatenate with the initial word representation. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Search for a suffixes vocabulary from Google.
2. Write a simple max-backward segmentation script to generate all words' suffixes, and add them as another item into your training and testing data, just like words and characters.
3. Concatenate suffix embedding with words and character embedding.

Comment: Firstly, the language I am working on is a low resource language, it doesn't have suffix vocabulary available in google. Secondly, in the thiird step you wrote "suffix embedding", how do you obtain the embeddings for suffixes in the first place?